# Bootstrap Pills CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a "Progress" indicator on one of my tools and I want to be able to show which steps have been completed by having a blue pill (the normal color) and then the ones that are not completed will have the grey (on hover) color.

Basically I need to be able to create a pill and have a class that is either .complete(blue) or .incomplete(grey). Neither of them have to have a hover color.

[image]

Currently the first pill is active in this default list and the second one I am just hovering over. I want the other 3 steps to be the grey color as will by default when they have the .incomplete class.

How would I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you post your code or create a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com)?

Comment: It's very basic, just uses the default pills.

http://www.bootply.com/98754

Comment: With the above link, just want all of the inactive ones to be the color that it changes on hover.

Comment: This is basic CSS. Apply the styles from the hover state to the default state in your LESS file or a CSS override file and be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav > li.incomplete > a {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.nav > li.complete > a {
    background-color: #428bca;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Yafb5

Comment: Moved the classes to the LI.

Comment: is it possible to include the "disabled" class in this as well? For example I want to have them grey but when you hover over them also have it disabled. I changed the li class to class="incomplete disabled" but when you hover over it, the background goes white.

Comment: All that is very possible. Please do some reading on the basics of CSS rather than just asking for the exact code you need.